# Derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to get derivative of $$ e^{-1/x^2} $$ (also in other points than 0, e.g. 1)

with

```
D[E[-1/x^2], x]
```

or

```
Series[E[-1/x^2], {x, 1, 10}, Assumptions -> x > 0],
```

but I get always zero derivatives.

When I do by hand derivative on paper in points other than 0, I don't get zero derivative.

Where's the problem?

Comment: try `Exp`, `E` is the number not the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always a good strategy to consider the options, see in this case,

- [E](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html)
- [Exp](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exp.html)

Sometimes a plot of known sizes is helpful and inspiring

```
Plot[{E, Exp[-1/x^2]}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

So,

```
der1 = D[Exp[-1/x^2], x]
```

leads to

$\frac{2 e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^3}$

and we can plot the result

```
Plot[{Exp[-1/x^2], der1}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]